# Using a custom python decorator accepting arguments with a cherrypy exposed endpoint

Tags: python, function, python-decorators, cherrypy

I am trying to monitor the latency of application using prometheus.There is a decorator function which calculates the time taken for a function to execute.Now as I wrap it with a cherrypy exposed endpoint there is no response from it.

I have also tried to use @cherrypy.tools.register('before_handler') over my decorator and then later attaching it as @cherrypy.tools.monitor_request() but it will through an argument exception as the decorator accepts a function.

```
def monitor_request(func):
    def inner1(*args, **kwargs):
        begin = time.time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        diff = end-begin
        REQUEST_LATENCY.labels(func.__name__).observe(diff)
        REQUEST_COUNT.labels(func.__name__).inc()
    return inner1


@cherrypy.expose
@monitor_request
def health1(self):
    """Give back health status"""
    return "is_healthy"
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return of `func` when called in `inner`. Either `func` has some side effects, or that is your problem.

Comment: Yes,the correct way is to store the return of func and later return at the end of inner1 function.

Comment: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah it worked.

Comment: Awesome. It would be fantastic if you could answer your own question, and maybe update the title to better reflect the issue you faced.

Comment: Yeah sure,done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not returning the result of response from cherrypy end point which was the issue.The correct code should be.

```
    def inner1(*args, **kwargs):
        begin = time.time()
        x = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        diff = end-begin
        REQUEST_LATENCY.labels(func.__name__).observe(diff)
        REQUEST_COUNT.labels(func.__name__).inc()
        return x
    return inner1
```